# Inkscape won't open .cdr files

Tags: kubuntu, inkscape

Hello I'm running `Kubuntu 12.04` and I've installed `Inkscape` because I need to edit a `.cdr` file, Inkscape works like normal but the sole task I need it to do is edit said `.cdr` file which I understand it should be capable off by default.

Whenever I try to open the file though I get the following error:

```
UniConvertor failed:
```

The eror itself is  longer but what it seems to be saying that it can't find this application, and I myself haven't found it in the package manager.

If someone has experienced something similar or has a simple solution for editing cdr's I'm no artist I just need to change some names, I would be very gratefull.

[The full error](http://pastebin.com/NMTEF2GV).

Comment: It can't find what application exactly?

Comment: the uniconverter

Comment: Try this: `mkdir ~/.uniconvertor`

Comment: Saddly creating that directory doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error log

```
   load_drawing_from_file
    raise SketchLoadError(_("unrecognised file type"))
    app.events.skexceptions.SketchLoadError: unrecognised file type
```

the CDR file ist not recognized.

What is the version of the CDR files? 
UniConvertor supports only the following CDR versions:

- CorelDRAW ver.7-X3,X4 (CDR/CDT/CCX/CDRX/CMX)

(Information from here: http://sk1project.org/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor)

Comment: `apt-cache search uniconverter` ;)

Comment: It said it was already installed and up to date, the uniconverter that is.

Comment: So, paste please the full error message, perhaps that helps

Comment: I put in a link to Pastebin in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see the info in the properties, and I just received this file with the instructions to add my name I don't know who designed it. I'm going to try and find out but I think this might be the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can find it under Ubuntu Software Center with the name **Universal Vector Graphics** Translator:
*python-uniconvertor*

OR

You can find uniconvertor .deb packages here:
http://sk1project.org/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor&op=download

Comment: I have them installed, now I found them in the software center, do you really think reinstalling from the .deb will solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice Draw, included with LibreOffice suite has the ability to open most CDR files flawlessly, just some specialized features may end needing manual fix after opening.